# "Нельзя преобразовать тип char к boolean" при сравнении строк

Tags: pascal

В лоб не понимаю, почему паскаль ругается на выражение `str[i] <> ' '`:

> Нельзя преобразовать тип char к
> boolean

```
program pr;
var str, str_new: string;
var i: integer;
begin
  writeln('введите строку с пробелами');
  readln(str);

  for i:= 0 to length(str) do begin
    if str[i] <> ' ' AND not (str[i] in ['а','о','е','ё','ю','я','э','ы','у','и']) then begin
      str_new := str_new + str[i];
    end;
  end;

  writeln(str_new);
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он ругается, потому что скобки забыты. Правильно условие записывается так

```
if (str[i] <> ' ') AND not (str[i] in ['а','о','е','ё','ю','я','э','ы','у','и'])
```

причина проста - AND более приоритетный, чем `<>`.

Comment: Ах эти приоритеты. Спасибо.